# Host: command not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, repository, bitbucket

doing Hartl's Rails book here and I'm supposed to add BitBucket(for the hello_app) and push it up the repository. However it just says the whole path/to/my/repo is missing (no file or directory like that). What could I have possibly done wrong? I already checked the ssh and it's a fit.

PS Id appreciate a laymanized response since I'm new to this whole programming thing. :) Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, mars, can you please tell the command that you've tried to run exactly ? Welcome to the community !

Comment: When asking any question, please assume that nobody else has seen, or can see, the book/screencast/etc to which you're referring, and encapsulate the problem in your question.

Comment: Please post the result of `git status`.

Comment: Hi @MaxWilliams so after creating a repo in BitBucket, Hartl's book tells me to run the command line > I have an existing project which would be $ cd /path/to/my/repo
$ git remote add origin git@bitbucket.org:mars_/hello_app.git
$ git push -u origin --all # pushes up the repo and its refs for the first time
$ git push -u origin --tags # pushes up any tags     -- butupon entering the first line the terminal tells me that there is no file or directory associated to that..

Comment: @TheGeorgeous this is the result of entering git status: On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean

Comment: Thank you @edi9999! The first command I was trying to run was $ cd /path/to/my/repo

Answer (score 0):

In the command  `$ cd /path/to/my/repo`, replace `/path/to/my/repo` with the actual path to where you created the repo.

For example (on a linux system and current user 'mars'):

```
$ mkdir /home/mars/hello-app
$ cd /home/mars/hello-app
$ git init
$ git remote add origin git@bitbucket.org:mars_/hello_app.git
```